# Python subprocess calling

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem with running files through python. 
This is my code :

```
def report1(self):
   str="/Users/Apple/Desktop/Report1.exe"
   subprocess.call(str)


This is the error i am getting : 
File "./DBMS.py", line 427, in <module>
Main().run();
File "./DBMS.py", line 415, in run
self.report1()
File "./DBMS.py", line 383, in report1
subprocess.call(str)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",      line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

PS: i tried changing permission rights on folders and i tried using subprocress.Popen . 
i also tried adding shell=True. i don't understand why its still not working .

any help is really appreciated.
have to submit in 24 hours :(

Comment: This is on Windows? Can you open a command prompt and run the exe outside of python?

Comment: this is on mac . working fine on windows :(

Comment: How are you expecting to run an exe file on a Mac?

Comment: I'm not an expert on macs, but generally you'd need an emulator like wine to run a windows exe on mac, and even then, only some programs will work that way.

Comment: i actually have wine on the mac but its not running it . daniel is right i think i have to make my executable not .exe

Comment: ok i now just made my executable file a unix file . sorry for asking a stupid question :)

Answer (score 1):

For all its merits, `subprocess` doesn't make it abundantly clear when an error has occurred while *trying* to execute a command.

If the deepest frame in your traceback (the one right before the actual exception) is `raise child_exception` from `subprocess.py`, that means there was some issue inclusively between the `fork(2)` and `exec*(2)` calls  -- in other words, that an error occurred while trying to run the command you requested.

The actual exception you pasted was `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.  An `errno` of `13` corresponds to `EACCES`:

```
>>> import errno; print errno.errorcode[13]
EACCES
```

If you've never used `fork(2)` or `exec(2)` things will be pretty inscrutable, because `subprocess` has dropped the real traceback.  However, I can tell you that this `OSError` almost certainly came from the `exec*` call. It turns out `execve` raises this under the following conditions:

```
 [EACCES]           Search permission is denied for a component of the
                    path prefix.

 [EACCES]           The new process file is not an ordinary file.

 [EACCES]           The new process file mode denies execute permission.

 [EACCES]           The new process file is on a filesystem mounted with
                    execution disabled (MNT_NOEXEC in <sys/mount.h>).
```

(Courtesy of [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/execve.2.html))

If I had to guess, you encountered this this exception because the command you're trying to run isn't marked executable (with something like `chmod u+x`).

Now, it's unlikely that your `.exe` file will run on your Mac after solving this, but at least it'll be a different error!

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program as sudo:

sudo python mycode.py